# Display Other Form Fields based on some selections

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, forms

Please, can someone help on this? Just like [booking.com](https://booking.com), I want to display a div based on user input. If the user selects 1 child, I'd like to display a form for *sex and age displays*, otherwise, if the number increases to 2, I want there **to be two of the div.**[image: Screenshot from booking.com]

Here is my code:

```
<div class="modal-body">
                                    <div class="">
                                        <div class="row" id="form-messages">
                                            <div class="col-sm-12">
                                                <form id="reused_form">
                                                    <div class="form-group">
                                                        <input type="text" name="name" required class="form-control" placeholder="Enter Name">
                                                    </div>
                                                    <div class="form-group">
                                                        <input type="email" name="email" required class="form-control" placeholder="Enter Email">
                                                    </div>
                                                    <div class="form-group">
                                                        <input type="tel" name="phone number" required class="form-control" placeholder="Enter Phone Number">
                                                    </div>
                                                    <div class="form-group" id="numberOfChildren">
                                                            <select class="form-control" name="childrenage">
                                                                    <option>Number of Children</option>
                                                                    <option value="option1">1</option>
                                                                    <option value="option1">2</option>
                                                                </select>
                                                        </div>
                                                    <div class="form-row" id="childrenData" style="display:none;">
                                                        <div class="form-group" style="width:47%;margin-right:3px">
                                                            <select class="form-control" name="childrenage">
                                                                <option>Sex</option>
                                                                <option>Male</option>
                                                                <option>Female</option>
                                                            </select>
                                                        </div>
                                                        <div class="form-group" style="width:47%; ">
                                                            <select class="form-control" name="childrenage">
                                                                <option>Children Age</option>
                                                                <option>1 Month</option>
                                                                <option>2 Month</option>
                                                                <option>3 Month</option>
                                                                <option>4 Month</option>
                                                                <option>5 Month</option>
                                                                <option>6 Month</option>
                                                                <option>7 Month</option>
                                                                <option>8 Month</option>
                                                                <option>9 Month</option>
                                                                <option>10 Month</option>
                                                                <option>11 Month</option>
                                                                <option>1 Year</option>
                                                                <option>2 Years</option>
                                                                <option>3 Years</option>
                                                                <option>4 Years</option>
                                                                <option>5 Years</option>
                                                                <option>6 Years</option>
                                                                <option>7 Years</option>
                                                                <option>8 Years</option>
                                                                <option>9 Years</option>
                                                                <option>10 Years</option>
                                                                <option>11 Years</option>
                                                                <option>12 Years</option>
                                                                <option>13 Years</option>
                                                                <option>14 Years</option>
                                                                <option>15 Years</option>
                                                                <option>16 Years</option>
                                                            </select>
                                                        </div>
                                                    </div>
                                                    <div class="form-group">
                                                        <button class="btn btn-raised btn-warning" type="submit" style="width:50%">View Lookbook</button>
                                                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary float-right" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                                                    </div>
                                                </form>
                                                <div id="error_message" style="width:100%; height:100%; display:none; ">
                                                    <h4>Error</h4>Sorry there was an error sending your form. 
                                                </div>
                                                <div id="success_message" style="width:100%; height:100%; display:none; ">
                                                    <h5>Your Message was Sent Successfully. <span><a href="./lookbook/" style="text-decoration: none; margin-left: 10px;" class="blink_me">Click here to view</a></span></h5>
                                                </div>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
```

...and here is the accompanying Javascript:

```
$(document).ready(function (){
            $("#numberOfChildren").change(function() {
                // foo is the id of the other select box 
                if ($(this).val() != "option1") {
                    $("#childrenData").show();
                }else{
                    $("#childrenData").hide();
                } 
            });
        });
```

Please, I need your help. I'm using html, js and php. Currently the code only works with one selection and I want it to work with up to 7 children.

Comment: [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/326569/under-what-circumstances-may-i-add-urgent-or-other-similar-phrases-to-my-quest). --- [Why is “Can someone help me?” not an actual question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/284236/why-is-can-someone-help-me-not-an-actual-question).

Comment: You'll need to write code and share the point where you get stuck.  Read this: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: *"Funky city flats"* - now that's for me.

Comment: @FunkFortyNiner Thank you. your point is noted.

Comment: @jmargolisvt Sorry IO forgot to include the code

Answer (score 1):

It's unlikely that booking.com is doing it this way and with your tech stack, but with the tools you've got, you can write an function to manage your DOM based on the value of that input.  Here is a basic/psuedo-code idea where you are going to read the input value (may need to `parseInt`) and run a loop that many times which appends your form html to a parent/container div.

```
        $("#numberOfChildren").change(function() {
            for (var i = 0; i < $(this).val(); i++) {
                $("#myNewContainerDivForTheseForms").append("<div><someForm></div>")
            }
        });
```

This is just one way to solve your problem, but you are going to encounter more issues afterward, like how you are going to manage the forms, their data, hiding/showing each one etc.  jQuery is not the right tool for that job imho, but I hope this gets you somewhere.